# Batch Loop used to reg query a list of keys from txt file and reuse data value

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, windows-registry

I need a batch loop that should extract a data value and use it in its next command. All registry keys I want to query has been saved into a *.txt file.

**Example:**

The following command will return the key value, type and data as per below.

**COMMAND:**

```
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\01690987922DC9549A63529D22383DDF\InstallProperties /V UninstallString
```

**RESULT:**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\01690987922DC9549A63529D22383DDF\InstallProperties
    UninstallString    REG_EXPAND_SZ    MsiExec.exe /X{78909610-D229-459C-A936-25D92283D3FD}
```

What I want to do is to extract only the data value `MsiExec.exe /X{78909610-D229-459C-A936-25D92283D3FD}` and run it as my next command in the for loop.

I have roughly 20 registry keys that I want to query and then run the extracted command. I also want to add silent switches to the msiexec.exe command when it is executed.

I'm very new to batch loops and believe I need to use tokens/delims(?)... not really sure how to get it working.

Comment: Do you need to use the cmd language or can you upgrade to a more capable tool (powershell, python, perl)?

Comment: Other methods are OK. We use Windows ADK/MDT for unattended OS/application installations and any form of legacy package should work fine. I reckon powershell would be the best fit if I take my colleagues into consideration.

Comment: @AlienLifeForm `cmd` is perfectly capable of such a trivial task ;)

Comment: @AlienLifeForm I also have cygwin as well. I just haven't gotten around to learning powershell.

Answer (score 1):

#### `reg query` a list of keys from a txt file and reuse data values

```
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\01690987922DC9549A63529D22383DDF\InstallProperties /V UninstallString
```

> What I want to do is to extract only the data values `MsiExec.exe` and  `/X{78909610-D229-459C-A936-25D92283D3FD}` and run it as my next command in the `for` loop.

The following batch file should get you started:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
rem get each key from keys.txt
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`type keys.txt`) do (
  echo Processing key %%i
  rem skip the first line and grab tokens 3 and 4 from the second line
  for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=3,4" %%j in (`reg query %%i`) do (
    echo %%j /quiet %%k
    )
  )
```

Notes:

- `keys.txt` should contain the keys to query, one per line.
- You need two `for` loops, the first to process each key, the second (inner) to parse the output.
- We skip the first line of output as it is the name of the key.
- Remove the `echo` from `echo %%j /quiet %%k` when you are happy with what the batch file is doing.
- I assume `/quiet` is the switch you need for "silent". Change as necessary.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.